# If statement isn't being caught

Tags: c, if-statement, statements

I can't for the life of me figure out why C is ignoring my if statement.

I'm trying to skip all the procedures in the while statement when the input is -1000 (so that it doesn't print before exiting the program). Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
  int count = 1;
  int grade1;
  int grade2;
  double sum;
  double average;

  printf("Please input a number of grades: \n");

  scanf("%d", &grade1);
  printf("Sum is: %d.000000 \n", grade1);
  printf("Average is: %d.000000 \n", grade1);
  count++;

  sum = grade1;

  while(grade2 != -1000) 
  {
    if(grade2 != -1000)
    {
      scanf("%d", &grade2);

      sum = sum + grade2;
      average = sum / count;

      printf("Sum is: %lf \n", sum);
      printf("Average is: %lf \n", average);

      grade1 = sum; //Converting the sum back into an int
      count++;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Here is a link to an image of my output. As you can see, even when grade2 is given -1000, the if statement is ignored, and another 2 lines are printed to the screen before the program exits. How can I fix this? Is this some sort of oddity of how C works?

Comment: What do you think the enclosing `while` loop does?

Comment: Please don't post an image of the output, copy the output in your question.

Comment: And you should use `do{}while()` instead of `while(){}`, because you need to check the looping condition after the body runs.

Comment: There's no need for the `if` statement, since it's the same condition as `while`.

Comment: @Barmar I think OP actually wants/needs the `if` statement. The problem is that the `scanf` should be before the `if` instead of inside the `if`

Comment: @4386427 Then he could just use `while(true)` and then `else { break; }`

Comment: @Barmar - True - there are many better ways to code this. But OP tried to fix the problem using the `if` - which is doable. So I think it has a value to explain how the problem is fixed while keeping the `if`

Comment: BTW, little need to use `sum` as `double`.  Just insure the average is calculated with `double` math,  `int sum = 0; ...... double average = 1.0* sum / count;`

Comment: Also, you don't initialize grade2, so the first test is random.

Comment: It isn't ignoring it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this the first time

```
  while(grade2 != -1000)
```

the variable `grade2` is uninitialized.

Consequently your code has undefined behavior

Make sure to initialize it like:

```
int grade2 = 0; // To zero or whatever you want
```

Further - always check the value returned by `scanf`. So instead of

```
scanf("%d", &grade1);
```

do

```
if (scanf("%d", &grade1) != 1)
{
    // Add error handling here
}
```

Your next problem is that you don't scan `grade2` before checking whether it is -1000. Move the scan before the if-statement.

Maybe what you want to do is:

```
  int grade2 = 0;
  while(grade2 != -1000) 
  {
      if (scanf("%d", &grade2) != 1)
      {
          // Add error handling here
      }
      if(grade2 != -1000)
      {
         ...
```

so that you scan for the first `grade2` before you do the `if(grade2 != -1000)` and enters the calculation code

Written differently this could be:

```
  while(1) 
  {
      if (scanf("%d", &grade2) != 1)
      {
          // Add error handling here
      }
      if(grade2 == -1000) break;  // Terminate the while

      sum = sum + grade2;
      ....
```

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that grade2 should be initialized and the return for scanf() should be checked, that's not the main problem the poster is running into.  The problem is that he checks

```
if(grade2 != -1000)
```

AFTER he has already processed grade2.  He should move

```
scanf("%d", &grade1);
```

before

```
if(grade2 != -1000)
```

Comment: Ah, yes, ofcourse. That makes total sense. Thank you Stephen!

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement in your `while` loop is redundant because, the loop will not iterate unless the condition that controls it is true, and the `if` statement comes directly after that, checking for the same condition, whilst `grade2` is unchaged.

Instead, you need to move it to after the `scanf()` call because that will modify the variable `grade2`, and don't forget to initialize your variables before using them or else you'll have undefined behavior.

```
int main(void)
{

    //....
    int grade2 = 0; // initialized...
    //....

    while (grade2 != -1000)
    {
        scanf("%d", &grade2);
        if (grade2 != -1000)
        {
            sum = sum + grade2;
            average = sum / count;

            printf("Sum is: %lf \n", sum);
            printf("Average is: %lf \n", average);

            grade1 = sum; //Converting the sum back into an int
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```